# factory_girlでhas_manyを作る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

factory_girlでpogepoge:hoge 1:nの関係を作ろうとしてます。
下記のように作成したのですが

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :pogepoge do
    association :user, factory: :user
    hoge 1
    birthday Date.today - 20.year
    after(:create) do |pogepoge|
      create(:hoge, pogepoge: pogepoge)
    end
  end
end
```

下記validationでエラーになってしまいます。

```
def hoge_exist
  if hoge.blank?
    errors.add(:hoge, :no_hoge)
  end
end
```

エラーにしない方法を知りたいです。
エラー内容は以下のような形で出ます。

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   translation missing: ja.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:14:in `block in initialize'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `[]'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `create'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:31:in `association'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:71:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:71:in `block in define_attribute'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
 # /Users/hoge/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/gemsets/ruby224/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
```

Comment: どんなエラーがでますか？　できる限り書いた方が、回答がつきやすいです。

Comment: スタックトレース追加しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。pogepogeのバリデーションで引っかかったのでbuildに変えました。

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :pogepoge do
    association :user, factory: :user
    hoge 1
    birthday Date.today - 20.year
    after(:build) do |pogepoge|
      pogepoge.hoges.build(attribute_for(:hoge))
    end
  end
end
```